# AWK Line of code printing to my output file when no print has been stated

Tags: regex, linux, awk

I'm intending to match some set of characters to the middle of a word, where I check the start and end of the word (it can't match the first or last characters otherwise my goal is void). Then I check if it exists in the word using

```
$1~/xampl/
```

The line of code I've come up with works perfectly, except when using

```
awk -f awkfile inputfile > outputfile
```

I want it to increment exists and not print, but it prints every time it matches... Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` programs follow this structure:

```
CONDITION { ACTIONS } [ CONDITION { ACTIIONS } ... ]
```

where either CONDITION or ACTIONS are optional. If the CONDITION is missing, like this:

```
awk '{ print }'
```

awk will assume the CONDITION to be `true` and execute the `{ print }` on every line of input.

If the ACTIONS are missing, like this (similar to your case):

```
awk '$1~/xampl/'
```

awk will run the *default action*, which is `{print}`. If you don't want to print but just increment you need to add an action, like this:

```
awk '$1~/xampl/ { c++ }'
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, your expression to match the word only when it appears in the middle of the first field is wrong. You're suffix index is off by two; it should be:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
"xampl"!=substr($1, 1, length("xampl")) && "xampl"!=substr($1, length($1)-length("xampl")+1, length("xampl")) && $1~/xampl/ {exists+=1}
```

which **can be shortened** to:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
$1~/.+xampl.+/ {exists++}
```

However, those scripts **have no side-effects**, i.e. all you do is increment a variable, but you never print it. This leads me to believe your error is actually in some other part of the script you are not showing us. Regardless, your `awk` program should not behave differently when invoked from a file.